# Multiple statements in THEN clause of CASE statements in Cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am pretty new to Neo4j. Is it possible to have an operation performed in the `THEN` clause of a `CASE` statement in `CYPHER` query? Something like, if the output of my current processing is null, then do something else. Snippet of what I am trying to do is below:

```
MATCH (order:PurchaseOrder)-[r:HAS_ITEM]->(a:sku) where a.id ='' and id(order) in OrderIDs

    with order as commonorders 
        CASE  WHEN  commonorders is not NULL THEN 

    [MATCH (commonorders)-[r:HAS_ITEM]->(a:sku) where a.id <> '888888888'
    return a]
ELSE
[ MATCH (order:PurchaseOrder)-[r:HAS_ITEM]->(a:sku) where a.id in [] and id(order) in OrderIDs

    WITH a as recommendedSku , count(r) as skuCount
ORDER BY skuCount DESC
LIMIT 5]

END
```

Comment: I thought I would let you know I formatted your post some. You will notice that in the body of you question, I formatted all the key words that are in it. This makes the post easier to read. I also re-formatted the code block so it is all in the same block, and so all the code is formatted. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks much! I shall definitely make that a practice in future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `THEN` and `ELSE` clauses cannot invoke `MATCH` (nor mutating operations, like `CREATE`). Also, a Cypher query cannot have multiple RETURN clauses (except when `UNION` is used, which would be inappropriate in your case).

You should split the query into two; or, if possible, modify your data model so that a single query would suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I shall probably split my query into two. Thanks